# Crack Windows 10 password with Cain and Able

Tags: password-cracking, file-encryption, windows-10, efs

A few months ago I reset my Windows password but my keyboard must have had a sticky key or two, effectively changing my password to an unknown password. Out of desperation and a little research I used **PCUnlocker** to forcefully reset my password. Little did I know that this would cause my `EFS` encrypted files to be unreadable.

My understanding is that non-domain, local user, Windows 10 passwords are based on the `NTLM` hashing algorithm.

Through much research I found an [article](https://www.filecritic.com/pcunlocker-review/) describing that a tool such as **Cain and Abel** that can help crack my old password by making use of `rainbow tables` and the old `SAM` file.

> After getting back into your system, you can install and run various
> password cracking software (for example, Ophcrack, Cain and Abel) to
> recover the old password in the original SAM file. After recovering
> the password, change the current password to the old password and
> you’ll gain access to the EFS encrypted files again.

I've created my own rainbow tables using the `Winrtgen` utility that comes packaged with Cain and Able and luckily PCUnlocker automatically backed up my `SAM` file. When cracking passwords with Cain and Able the UI asks for a `SAM` file and the `SYSTEM` file where the latter to my knowledge does not change when resetting a password. *(Correct me if I'm wrong on this.)*

The rainbow tables that I generated vary, however the one which I expected to work was based on the `mixalpha-numeric-all` type *i.e upper + lower-case of alphanumeric and all special characters*. The password I used can range in between 25-33 characters (accounting for several sticky charters)

All in all I have not been successful in cracking my password with my old `SAM` file, my current `SYSTEM` file, and my custom rainbow tables.

### Questions

1. Are rainbow tables less effective the more potential characters there are? (e.g., lower-cased only vs. mixed-cased + special characters)
2. Does the salted hash in the `SYSTEM` file change when changing passwords?
3. Any other suggestions?

Comment: 1. The hash is not salted. 2. Cain is ancient. Try John the ripper with a wordlist and a good rule set like dive or korelogic. Use pypykatz or impacket to extract the hash beforehand. 3. Rainbow tables are not useful if you want to crack a single hash. Don't bother.

Comment: @Volker Thanks for your suggestions, I will do some more research. I do want to point out that a wordlist (based on a dictionary?) would likely not work in my case as my passwords are randomized. But I will look into John the Ripper + dive or korelogic rule sets. Can you expand on why Rainbow tables are not useful if you want to crack a single hash please?

Comment: Oh, if they're randomized, I'd use john in incremental mode.

Rainbow tables save you computing the hash of a password candidate a second time. You trade computing power for storage. So you can compute a huge rainbow table in advance and store it on a huge hard drive (and possibly share it with others). When you then encounter a new hash, you simply look it up instead of computing it. But computing a rainbow table for a single hash does not make sense.